# Spring webflow PropertyNotFoundException: Property not found

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I am trying to set a variable inside session scope from spring webflow xml definition and hitting property not found..please help

> 118484 [http-8080-6] DEBUG servlet.YBRServlet  - Handler execution
>   resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view:
>   ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'Err010DfltCrtc'; model is
>   {exception=org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@87ba9e targetAction =
>   [SetAction@1ed364c name =
>   flowRequestContext.externalContext.sessionMap.testCompleted, value =
>   yes], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'AnnIncr' of flow
>   'QlfyEnrl' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'}
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@87ba9e targetAction =
>   [SetAction@1ed364c name =
>   flowRequestContext.externalContext.sessionMap.testCompleted, value =
>   yes], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'AnnIncr' of flow
>   'QlfyEnrl' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)
>     at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:193)   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.binding.expression.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   Property not found    at
>   org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:87)
>     at
>
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1008E**:(pos 0): Field or property 'yes' cannot be found on object of**
>   type
>   'org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl'
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
>     ... 88 more

Flow Code

```
<view-state id="AnnIncr" view="AnnIncr" model="ssModel">
<on-entry>

            <set name="flowRequestContext.externalContext.sessionMap.testCompleted" value="yes"></set>
        </on-entry>
.....
    <on-exit>
    <set name="flowRequestContext.externalContext.sessionMap.testCompleted" value="no"></set>
    </on-exit>
</view-state>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and format it correctly.  Don't use block-quote notation for code, indent it 4 spaces.

Comment: Root cause: `Field or property 'yes' cannot be found on object of type org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl' `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem, within double quote I have to wrap value with single quote to represent it as a value otherwise it expect a expression here.

```
 <set name="flowRequestContext.externalContext.sessionMap.testCompleted" value="yes"></set>
```

it should be

```
<set name="flowRequestContext.externalContext.sessionMap.testCompleted" value="'yes'"></set>
```